# Counting the number of elements of an array but with a condition

Tags: count

I have an array with real numbers, say A. I have calculated the mean as np.mean(A)

Now I want to check how many elements fell below the mean and how many above.

for example

A = [ 1 2 3 5] so the average is 2.75. So, i have two elements below the average and two elements above.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could do:

```
function mean(array){
    var sum=0;
    for (item in array){
        sum = sum + array[item];
    }
    return sum/(array.length)
}

function belowMean(array) {
    return array.filter(function(item){
        return item < mean(array);
    });
}

var a=[1,2,3,4];
alert(mean(a));

alert(belowMean(a)); //you'll get an array with those elements below the mean.
alert(belowMean(a).length); //you'll get how many elements are below the mean.
```

It's ugly though, I'd rather modified the array prototype to tho so.

Answer (score 0):

How about loop it twice? First time for average value and second time for your count?